# How to compare two strings?

Tags: c, string

I am working with Eclipse and I am facing a problem that I don't know how to solve! I have a function with one of its parameters being a string. I made a parameter that I gave it a string. Now I try to compare the two strings with an `if` statement, and the two strings have the same value, but the `if` statement didn't succeed! Even though I am checking the code with a debugger and I am going step by step, and I can see that `r_name` and `check_name` both have the same string! What I have done:

```
v_function(CSystem *sss, char *r_name) {
  char *check_name = (((sss)->rarray)->name);// here check_name=str_vv

  printf("check_name=%s\n",check_name);      //it prints check_name=str_vv
  printf("r_name=%s\n",r_name);              //it prints r_name=str_vv

  if(!strcmp(check_name,r_name)){            //if statement is not working !!!
     // do something
  }
}
```

Yes, I checked in the debugger and it doesn't enter the `if` statement. I tried to do: `if(check_name==r_name)` also, but the same exact problem happens when I step in the debugger.

_Does this matter? In the value window (which appears when I use the debugger) the two parameters have the following values: for `r_name`   the value is: `0x40a039 "str_vv"`, and for `check_name`  the value is :  `0x40a02f "str_vv"`. I assume the numbers here are the address, because as I said the `printf` prints the same exact string "str_vv" ... but does the address shown in the value window of the debugger matter?

Comment: consider using more whitespace. Your code gives me a headache when i look at it.

Comment: Is check_name null terminated?

Comment: Do a strlen of the strings and see if they are of the exact same length

Comment: sorry paul lol next time :)

Comment: You're not showing enough code for me to rule out _undefined behaviour_ as the cause here.

Comment: this is litrally the problem !! the code is more than 500 lines ! but the problem is here with the debbuger

Comment: how can i edit the question ??

Comment: Click on the "edit" link right below the question.

Comment: Maybe the strings have whitespace around them that's different.

Comment: Several things can cause `strcmp()` to behave in manner you thought was wrong. non-nul terminated string on either or both strings, non-printable characters on either or both strings including spaces. When debugging, make it a habit to check the length of the strings and print with delimiters around tha vlues like `printf("check_name=[%s]\n",check_name);`.

Comment: Just set a breakpoint in the debugger, it should have a command to display the exact contents of the strings.

Comment: i updated the question if you want to check it :(

Comment: now it works eve thogh i didn't change a thing ! and i tried it like 20 times i am not exagirating !! this eclipse will drive me crazy :'(

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a `\r` at the end of one of the strings and not the other?  Have you printed a hex dump of the outputs?  Have you wrapped the `%s` in a marker, such as `printf("[[%s]]\n", check_name);` — a suggestion also made by @alvits.  If the close brackets are misplaced, that indicates a problem.

Comment: @lauren - if it suddenly worked but didn't, it's symptomatic of undefined behavior. Undefined behavior is just that __undefined__. Sometimes it will work, other times it won't work.

Comment: This comment is not addressing the issue.  But wouldn't this `(((sss)->rarray)->name)` be easier to read if all parenthesis are gone?  To me `sss->rarray->name` is much simpler to read.  Is there a reason for all these parenthesis?

Comment: Have you tried `strncmp(  , , n)`?  In the above example is 
 true, `strncmp(check_name,r_name, 6)` should evaluate to true.  `strncmp()` checks first 6 characters of each variables.